# CSS rule ignored in IE8 Quirks Mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a ul/li based side menu, styled with two CSS rules, the following of them is ignored by IE8 Quirks mode, and I assume IE6:

```
ul { padding-left: 15px; }
```

I can reproduce the problem in FF by removing this rule completely.  I have also tried using jQuery to apply the rule, with no change in IE8:

```
$("ul.menu-class").find("ul").css("padding-left", 15);
```

Is this a box model issue, and, how can I reduce the UL 'padding' in IE Quirks Mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `margin-left` for IE - browsers have a unique look on that matter.